# Spring boot takes a long time to bootstrap

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing my demo application and when it bootstraps it takes a long time. In this application I use spring JPA with my local Oracle database.

What is wrong?

I have added a screenshot of the console below:

[image]

Comment: Hikari is taking 700ms to start which would suggest that your database, or the network connection to it, is rather slow. There may be other things too. Can you copy-paste the complete output into your question rather than only sharing a screenshot of some of it.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thank you for the attention on my issue. I've updated the main question with a detailed screenshot of the console. Please do inform me if you require more information.

Comment: There’s almost two minutes between consecutive lines of output, both of which are from Hibernate. It’s looking increasingly like the DB that your app is using is the bottleneck.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am thinking the same but that cannot  be normal. There has to be something blocking and that is why it takes so long. If I use an embedded H2 database for dev purposes, this it wouldn't take so long to bootstrap. Do you have any suggestion for me to further investigate on this matter ?

Comment: I would start with the DB itself and the network connection to it. You could try connecting using its CLI and see if it’s slow there too.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks for your input. I will further investigate in that path,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is taking approx 2 minutes between the below lines

[image]

There are couple of possibilites here.
If you have configured for auto update of database then it might be taking time to check you database metadata ( table structure, indexes, foreign keys etc)
with the current entities in your code base and because of slow link this might have even further be causing the startup to take more time.
Also looks like you are using JTA transaction manager and it could also take time to initialize.

You can try attaching jvisualvm to your application and then take multiple thread dumps (maybe in 10 s interval starting from the point when the
startup seems to freeze) and then later analyze the thread dump to see a common thread stack which is hung. You can use thread dump analyzer tools as listed
[here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-analyze-thread-dumps) to ease the analysis. Another way could be to use CPU profiling option in jvisualvm which can point you to methods taking too long (hotspots) while startup.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, I was helpless without knowing from where should I start. Thanks for giving me an idea to further investigate on this.